# Realm React Native: Filtering based on last object in list

Tags: react-native, realm

How do I do a query filtered by attributes in a child object in Realm React Native

Here's my (simplified) schema.

```
Habit.schema = {
    name: 'Habit',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int', 
        name: 'string',
        intervals: {type:'list', objectType: 'Interval'}
    }
}

Interval.schema = {
    name: 'Interval',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int', 
        intervalStart: 'date',
        intervalEnd: 'date',
        allComplete: 'bool',
    }
}
```

I tried doing:

```
let filteredHabits = realm.objects('Habit').filtered('intervals.intervalStart < $0 AND intervals.intervalEnd > $0 AND intervals.allComplete == false', new Date());
```

But what this seems to be doing is going through all of the of the intervals with all of the habits, and as long as one of the intervals start before the current time and another interval ends before the current time, it will miss the filter.

What I'd like to do is a query based on the very LAST interval in the list. If I can't do that, is there a way to make sure that it's comparing the attributes of just a single interval, and not all of them?

Answer (score 1):

The predicate language used by Realm for React Native does not yet directly support the type of query you're after. I'd encourage you to [file a feature request](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/new) asking for it. In the mean time, you can work around this limitation by performing the filtering in JavaScript.

Comment: That's eventually what I did :)